Problems at login
I have this login process (some parts will be omitted):
Index.cshtml.cs (Login):
var cookieOptions = new CookieOptions
{
    HttpOnly = true,
    Secure = cookieSecurePolicy,
    SameSite = cookieSameSite
};

Response.Cookies.Append(".AspNetCore.Identity.SessionToken", dtoUser.SessionToken, cookieOptions);

return RedirectToPage("/dialogues/index");

And the Middleware:
public class SessionTokenMiddleware
{
    private readonly ILogger<SessionTokenMiddleware> _logger;
    private readonly RequestDelegate _next;

    public SessionTokenMiddleware(ILogger<SessionTokenMiddleware> logger, RequestDelegate next)
    {
        _logger = logger;
        _next = next;
    }

    public async Task Invoke(HttpContext httpContext, IPersistance cache)
    {
        if (httpContext.User != null && httpContext.User.Identity != null && httpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            var cookieSessionToken = httpContext.Request.Cookies[".AspNetCore.Identity.SessionToken"];

            if (cookieSessionToken == null)
            {
                await httpContext.SignOutAsync(IdentityConstants.ApplicationScheme);
            }
            else
            {
                var userId = httpContext.User.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier)?.Value;

                var dtoUserAuthenticated = cache.Get<DTO.UAC.User>(userId);

                if (dtoUserAuthenticated == null || cookieSessionToken != dtoUserAuthenticated.SessionToken)
                {
                    await httpContext.SignOutAsync(IdentityConstants.ApplicationScheme);
                    httpContext.Response.Redirect("/login?errorCode=accountInUse");
                    return;
                }
            }
        }

        await _next(httpContext);
    }
}

The problem here is: When the login process is succesfull, the application do not redirect the user to the "dialogues/index" and I can't figure out why.
If you need more information, ask and I will provide.
Edit: I forgot to mention, this application is been deployed in a Kubernetes Cluster and just don't work there; on my local environment, my machine, it's works like a charm.
